# Nodes midway sloped - how?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

[image]
I have the picture, MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1.5:3,scale=0.8]
\draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-3,-2) grid (10,6.5);
\foreach \x in {-3,...,9} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
\foreach \y in {-2,...,6} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};
\node at (3.5,5) {$B$};
\node at (9,-0.5) {$C$};
\node at (-2,-0.6) {$A$};
\filldraw[black] (-2, -1) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (4, 5) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (8, 0) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (3, -0.5) circle(1.5pt);
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (10,0) node[below right] {$X$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Y$};
\draw[color=green!40!black,ultra thick][domain=-2.5:5] plot (\x, 1+\x) node[right] {$x-y+1=0$};
\draw[color=red!60!black,ultra thick][domain=3:9.5] plot (\x, 10-5/4*\x) node[below,left] {$5x+4y-40=0$};
\draw[color=red,ultra thick][domain=-3:9.5] plot (\x,-4/5+1/10*\x) node[right,above] {$x-10y-8=0$};
\draw[thick,dashed][domain=3.9:4.65] plot (\x,45-10*\x) node[right,above] {$H_B$};
\draw[thick,dashed,blue][domain=2.8:4.2] plot (\x,-17+5.5*\x) node[right,above] {$M_B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to place line's equations in the middle of the line, sloped. If I use options `node[midway,sloped]` then have no nice result. How can I place these equations correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

If I'm not wrong, it's difficult to insert `nodes` over a path defined with `plot` option which is what you used to draw the final lines.

The solution consists in drawing the line with `plot` and use another command to place the label over it.

In following code there are some other changes respect your original code.

The first one is that instead of drawing (hidden) circles and labeling them later on, I've used a `dot` node with a label:

```
\node[dot, label=100:$A$] at (-2, -1) (A) {};
```

This way I can use `(A)` as a reference to this point.

No changes are med to `plot` commands except suppressing end nodes because corresponding equation will be written later.

As nodes A, B and C are already defined, they can serve as a reference for straight lines which will be used to place the equations. As an example:

```
\path (B) -- node[sloped, above, color=red!60!black] {$5x+4y-40=0$} (C);
```

I've tried to adjust equations placement with `pos` and `above/below` options, but you can adjust as you like.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1.5:3, 
    scale=0.8,
    dot/.style={circle, draw, fill, minimum size=1.5pt, inner sep=1pt}
    ]
\draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-3,-2) grid (10,6.5);
\foreach \x in {-3,...,9} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
\foreach \y in {-2,...,6} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};

\node[dot, label=100:$A$] at (-2, -1) (A) {};
\node[dot, label=west:$B$] at (4, 5) (B) {};
\node[dot, label=80:$C$] at (8, 0) (C) {};

\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (10,0) node[below right] {$X$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Y$};

\draw[color=green!40!black,ultra thick][domain=-2.5:5] plot (\x, 1+\x);
\path (A) -- node[pos=.65, sloped, above, color=green!40!black] {$x-y+1=0$} (B);

\draw[color=red!60!black,ultra thick][domain=3:9.5] plot (\x, 10-5/4*\x);
\path (B) -- node[sloped, above, color=red!60!black] {$5x+4y-40=0$} (C);

\draw[color=red,ultra thick][domain=-3:9.5] plot (\x,-4/5+1/10*\x);
\path (A) -- node[pos=.85,sloped, below=1mm, color=red] {$x-10y-8=0$} (C);

\draw[thick,dashed][domain=3.9:4.65] plot (\x,45-10*\x) node[right,below] {$H_B$};
\draw[thick,dashed,blue][domain=2.8:4.2] plot (\x,-17+5.5*\x) node[right,above] {$M_B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```